# Is there a way to support different coding styles in a development team

Tags: coding-style

The Problem: Two developers => three opinions on indention, braces on new line or not etc.

We usually work with three or four people on our projects and each of those has it's own code style. I know, the common solution is to agree on a code style, everybody has to use, but I don't want to force creative programmers in a suit that does not fit them.

So the question is: Is there a way to let each programmer live his/her own style, but having a common code base inside the repository? I think of some git/svn/whatever plugin, which changes between personal and common style on checkout and commit. It appears to me, that the tricky part in this approach is to support correct diffs between the versions of a file

Comment: I'd say it's far easier to force developers to conform to team/project standards instead. =)

Comment: Possibly should be moved to Programmers

Comment: Moved to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/189425/83381

Answer (score 1):

It's not too late for the "pick one and stick with it" decision (even if it's not the one you prefer).

For the existing code base, stick with what ever convention was used in that file.

If that module ever gets a (near) re-write, or a large overhaul then change it then.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, in my opinion, that most developers (which I met) didn't like to change the coding standard with they feel comfortable, even for a while.

For example back in the days when I was Web Developer, none of my co-workers change the coding style even for 1 file, it just doesn't make sense to have nicely formatted file with PEAR Coding Standard, and someone to write several functions hundred lines of cone in CamelCase/camelBack or whatever standard they use.

So in your case it is important to make good team and if the team have respect to each other they will come with the idea to write in unified standard to lower the needed code maintenance.